# How to create a new GA tracker, if already be another tracker

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In my case, I have a SPA. On the first page created 1 ga tracker and on the second page I want to create another 3 ga trackers, but the create method not working:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

Help me, please. Maybe there is an option to destroy all trackers and create new ones?

Comment: Did you read the documentation page? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers It shows how to create multiple named trackers.

Answer (score 0):

As [Sergiu pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65717186/#comment116192196_65717186) in the comment, the developer manual [provides an example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers) for your case.

You would need to create multiple trackers, providing each additional tracker with a unique name. The name can be passed via the optional fourth argument. So, to work with three trackers at the same time, you can modify your code this way:

```js
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'clientTracker1');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'clientTracker2');
```

To track an event in this case, you would need to prefix the command with the tracker name. Sending an event without specifying the tracker name would be treated as sending with the default tracker:

```js
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('clientTracker1.send', 'pageview');
ga('clientTracker2.send', 'pageview');
```